# Editor with live preview for AsciiDoc

Tags: text-editor, editing, asciidoc

I'm looking for something like ReText, but for AsciiDoc.

The closest I have found is [this relatively complex solution](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/editing-asciidoc-with-live-preview/) (or [here](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor.org/blob/master/docs/editing-asciidoc-with-live-preview.adoc)) involving Ruby, guard, guard-shell, rb-inotify, asciidoctor, [Epiphany](http://projects.gnome.org/epiphany/) (or another browser with [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/)).

I'll do all that if it is the best option. But I was looking for just a simple solution, along the lines of a [ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/retext) for AsciiDoc.

I also heard that O'Reilly has some [tools](http://www.oreilly.com/authors/welcome/asciidoc.csp) (e.g., the Atlas wiki interface), but I'm not submitting my documents to O'Reilly. (Atlas looks cool and I'd consider using it if I could do so privately.)

Anyone have another suggestion?

Comment: I opened a ticket: https://sourceforge.net/p/retext/tickets/113/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsciiDoctor provides a nice [Overview of Editing AsciiDoc with Live Preview](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor/latest/tooling/).

It includes details on how to setup many of the tools mentioned here, e.g. AsciidocFX, Atom, Brackets and IntelliJ.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [AsciidocFX](https://github.com/rahmanusta/AsciidocFX) on any platform.

There are many features:

- Real-Time Preview
- Multi-platform (Windows, Mac, Linux ..)
- Creating Asciidoc Books
- Creating Markdown Books
- Creating PDF, HTML, Epub, Mobi, Docbook
- Epub Viewer
- External Browser Support
- Table Generator
- MathJax Extension
- PlantUML Extension
- Filesystem Tree Extension
- JavaFX Charts Extension

Comment: That looks pretty good. Can it edit in Preview mode? I'm looking for an asciidoc editor that can do WYSIWYG editing (not just a live preview).

Comment: Unfortunately, the AsciidocFX editor is very slow. Even with turned off preview, I have to wait the typed letters to appear. Selecting words is even slower.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use atom.io with the plugin asciidoc-preview :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9o-0J2YKZ4

Comment: atom.io looks exciting. I'll check it out. Thanks

Comment: asciidoc-preview for atom does not support PlantUML that makes it useless.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Asciidoctor.js Live Preview browser extension to render AsciiDoc (.ad, .adoc, .asc, .asciidoc) as HTML.

1. Install it for either [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/asciidoctorjs-live-previe/iaalpfgpbocpdfblpnhhgllgbdbchmia) or [Firefox](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-browser-extension).
2. For Firefox, you'll need to download the latest xpi file (link on the README).
3. For Chrome, you'll likely want to enable Allow access to local file URLs under the extension options.
4. Then either point your browser at a remote AsciiDoc URL or create a new file locally (e.g. `helloworld.adoc`), enter some text in it with your favorite editor, and then point your browser to it (e.g. `file:///home/ggrossetie/helloworld.adoc`).

Comment: New version of AsciiDoctor.js is found here: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-browser-extension

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio Code also comes with a nice [AsciiDoc plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joaompinto.asciidoctor-vscode):

> [image]

Comment: This plugin also uses AsciiDoctor.js.

Answer (score 1):

[Brackets Editor](http://brackets.io/) has a AsciiDoc Preview [Extension](https://github.com/asciidoctor/brackets-asciidoc-preview) that I am using right now. Works well.

Comment: Should we trust Adobe to support Ubuntu going forward?

Comment: It is an opensource project. Code available on github [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets)
Here is the [License](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/master/LICENSE)